# ChangeListener not working as intended for JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, changelistener

I want to detect when a tab is changed and retrieve the selected index. All the examples I've been able to find seem outdated and I haven't been able to implement them successfully.

It forces me to cast my changeListener to javax.swing.event.ChangeListener, but at the same time doesn't let me compile that. Where am i going wrong?

```
ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
          public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
            int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
            System.out.println("Tab changed to: " + index);
          }

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        };
        tabbedPane.addChangeListener((javax.swing.event.ChangeListener) changeListener);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're implementing the wrong `ChangeListener` when you invoke `new ChangeListener`. Check your imports. You should be implementing `javax.swing.event.ChangeListener` but it looks like you're actually implementing `javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener`.

If you don't want to change your imports, the following would work too.

```
  javax.swing.event.ChangeListener changeListener = new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) e.getSource();
        int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();
        System.out.println("Tab changed to: " + index);
      }
    };
    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(changeListener);
```

Answer (score 2):

The wrong `ChangeListener` is being imported - check the corresponding import statement. It should be

```
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
// or import javax.swing.event.*;
```

Probably the wrong class is being imported as in:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
// or import javafx.beans.value.*;
```

If these imports (javaFX) are being needed, you must use the fully qualified class name when creating the listener:

```
javax.swing.event.ChangeListener changeListener = 
    new javax.swing.event.ChangeListener() {
        ...
```